# Get position with variable and then modify specific object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

How can I make this query use my variable instead of the hard coded 0?

```
let pos = 0;

{$set: {'answers.0.acknowledged': data}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you choices are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [String.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) etc:

```js
let pos = 0;
let data = 'data';

let query = {$set: {[['answers.', pos,'.acknowledged'].join('')]: data}}

console.log(query);
```

With [String.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat):

```js
let pos = 0;
let data = 'data';
let query = {$set: {['answers.'.concat(pos,'.acknowledged')]: data}}
console.log(query);
```

[Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Browser_compatibility), [String.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat#Browser_compatibility) has a much better browsers support where [template literals do not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility). If they were to be used @ the client side. In your case if you are using them at the back end you probably have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 [String Interpolation](http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation) and [Computed Property Names](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames) to build the key for `$set`:

```js
let pos = 0;
let data = 'some data';
let q = {$set: {[`answers.${pos}.acknowledged`]: data}}
console.log(q);
```